# How to integrate Unitymol with Unity3D project?

Tags: unity-game-engine, htc-vive

Firstly, thanks for bothering your time reading this problem.

I recently want to develop a Unity3D project which serves for **molecular visualization** on **HTC Vive** with the help of **SteamVR**. I've found that **Unitymol** is a suitable solution to visualize PDB files, but I have problem import them into Unity3D, because I fail to figure out how can I export models/gameobjects from Unitymol.

What should I do? In fact, what I need is to import PDB files into Unity3D. Blender is not a acceptable solution because it can't load large PDB files and need much work to do after importation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am one of the developer of UnityMol. 
For now, this project is not fully open sourced and you need the sources to extract generated GameObjects. 
You can ask for Marc Baaden to initiate à collaboration. 
We have scripts to create Unity assets and use them in other projects. 
If you are trying to visualize molecules in VR, we already are doing this in UnityMol VR.

Comment: Well, thank you for your answer. I've gotten contact with Badden, and I've known that it's not public yet. May I ask that whether it will be public in the end and how long it will take?(By the way, visualizing molecules in VR is not exactly what I want to do....I just want to find a way to simplify the importation of molecular models to Unity3D)